# What is "winneuse"? Anybody knows the meaning of this word?

Tags: vocabulaire

I saw this word in some forums, but didn't get the meaning or translation for it, could someone explain it to me?

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/winner

Answer (score 2):

Une winneuse would be the feminine form of slang term "un winner". The usage of this word by native French speakers is, in my experience, generally sarcastic — it doesn't usually mean "someone who wins". It can mean someone who really lucked out ("avoir de la win" is a slang term for being lucky, opposed to "avoir de la loose", pronounced like "looz") or someone who is really stupid ("il a une bonne tête de winner" means "he looks so dumb", as in able to win a dumbness contest). Having more context would be useful to be able to really help.

Comment: I was wondering if "un winner" didn't come from the movie "le diner de cons" (or maybe even the theatre play) and the famous "Il a une belle tête de vainqueur"

Comment: I speculate the same but wasn't able to source it.

Answer (score 1):

**Winneuse** is the feminine french version of a "winner". It would be "**winneur**" for a male.